# Auto Update of Values in UI WPF form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, bindinglist

I have a class as follows:

```
Public Class BillAmounts
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChange(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
    Private _LabourCostValue As Double
    Private _TransportPriceValue As Double
    Private _ItemsTotalCost_ As Double
    Private _FinalPriceValue As Double
    Property TransportPrice As Double
        Get
            Return _TransportPriceValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If Not _TransportPriceValue = value Then
                _TransportPriceValue = value
                _FinalPriceValue = TransportPrice + LabourCost + ItemsTotalCost_
                PriceCalculationNotification()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Property LabourCost As Double
        Get
            Return _LabourCostValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Double)
            If Not _LabourCostValue = Value Then
                _LabourCostValue = Value
                _FinalPriceValue = TransportPrice + LabourCost + ItemsTotalCost_
                PriceCalculationNotification()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Property ItemsTotalCost_ As Double
        Get
            Return _ItemsTotalCost_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If Not _ItemsTotalCost_ = value Then
                _ItemsTotalCost_ = value
                FinalPrice = TransportPrice + LabourCost + ItemsTotalCost_
                'NotifyPropertyChange("ItemsTotalCost_")
                PriceCalculationNotification()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    ReadOnly Property TotalPrice As Double
        Get
            Try
                Return ItemsTotalCost_ + TransportPrice + LabourCost
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return 0
            End Try
        End Get
        'Set(ByVal value As Double)
        '    If Not _TotalpriceValue = value Then
        '        _TotalpriceValue = value
        '        NotifyPropertyChange("TotalPrice")
        '    End If
        'End Set
    End Property
    Property FinalPrice As Double
        Get
            Return _FinalPriceValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If Not _FinalPriceValue = value Then
                _FinalPriceValue = value
                PriceCalculationNotification()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    ReadOnly Property Discount_ As Double
        Get
            '_Discount_ = FinalPrice - TotalPrice
            'Return _Discount_
            Return FinalPrice - TotalPrice
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _TransportPriceValue = 0
        _LabourCostValue = 0
        _ItemsTotalCost_ = 0
        _FinalPriceValue = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub PriceCalculationNotification()
        NotifyPropertyChange("TransportPrice")
        NotifyPropertyChange("LabourCost")
        NotifyPropertyChange("Discount_")
        NotifyPropertyChange("TotalPrice")
        NotifyPropertyChange("FinalPrice")
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have the bound the fields as follows:

```
<StackPanel Name="AmountStack" Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="Transport"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TransportPrice}" Name="TransportTxtBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Labour"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding LabourCost}" Name="labourTxtBox" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    <TextBlock Text="Total Amount =" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" Name="TotalTextBox"  IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Discount= " VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Discount_, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Name="DiscountTextBox" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Total Amount = " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FinalPrice}" Name="FinalTotalTextBox" Width="130" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
```

and

```
AmountStack.DataContext = Bill.Amounts
```

However, the issue is that TOtalAMount is getting updated automatically but FinalPrice is not getting updated.  Any reasons/mistakes I have done.  I have tried it a lot in few ways but could not get that working.  What i did not understand is that Total amount is getting updated but Final price isn't.  Thank you.

Comment: Tried this on VS2010 SP1.  Only problem was binding to which needs to have Mode=OneWay added to the binding because TotalPrice is readonly.  What version of VS/.Net are you using?

Comment: Try debugging the bindings that don't work using `PresentationTracesources.TraceLevel`. See [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52) for more info. This will help you see whether the binding gets updates or not. If not do the usual breakpoint, step-through thing...

Comment: @ grantnz - I am using VS2010.  @Sebastian Edelmeier, I used the breakpoints and watches, the values i getting updated yet the issue is only from UI.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not remember the source but the point is when there is read only property the binding does not work correctly some times and is waiting for a fix in next release, I solved by manually coding for change by text change events.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Private _FinalPriceValue` to assign value in Setter `TransportPrice` and `LabourCost`. Use `FinalPrice` to raise `PriceCalculationNotification()` everytime properly.

Comment: I did the change, that is a performance bonus.  But UI is not getting updated yet.